# Installing Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 8

Tags: windows, ubuntu, partitioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install Windows alongside Ubuntu?](https://superuser.com/questions/261195/how-can-i-install-windows-alongside-ubuntu)

I've installed Windows on half of my hard disk space. Only one partition. I would like to install Ubuntu into my free disk space. The question:

At Ubuntu Installer, when I choose "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows", what's the next step: installer will realocate my NTFS partition, ignoring my free space or it will install Ubuntu into my free disk space, automatically?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Typical behavior is it will utilize all the free, unallocated space for the partitions it wants to make. Then once installation is complete it will configure grub to offer you Ubutnu and Windows 7 boot options.

If you are worried about it messing with your Windows 7 install you can manually handle the partitioning, and it will still automate the grub configuration to reflect booting either.

Answer (score 0):

Depends

1> When you installed your windows if you formatted the entire drive as NTFS. Linux will have no choice other than deleting and installing.

```
 The solution: 
   * Use gpartd from one of the ubuntu live CD and adjust the unused NTFS disk filesystem.
```

2> When installing the windows with partially formatted NTFS. Eg:- on a 100G drive lets say you formatted only 50G as NTFS. The linux installation will automatically use the unformatted disk space.